# What is included when making a jar file?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

When I build my project (using the Netbeans IDE) will it only take the main class, or will it include the other classes in the project even though they are not explicitly declared within the code for the main class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All  classes in a package  are included in a jar file. You can cross-check it by following this:

Go to **dist folder** of the project.

**Extract the jar** file with any file archiver(`eg: 7-zip, winrar, winzip`).

The **extracted folder** contains all the contents that are included in a jar file.

Example:

**Test** is a **main** class

**Test.java**:

```
package test;
public class Test 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
}
```

There is another class: **class1**

**class1.java**:

```
package test;
public class class1 
{

}
```

class1.java is not explicitly declared within the code for the main class(Test).But when I build this project in a Net-beans IDE and extracted the jar file(Test.jar).The jar contains:

1. `class1.class`
2. `Test.class`

Answer (score 0):

What goes in a JAR and what remains out depends on the packaging agent, so this is definitely IDE-dependent, and also depends on the configuration options used to build the archive (for example if it's a lib JAR, if it's an executable JAR, if it's a WAR, and so on).

For example, Eclipse can package your compiled sources along with the JAR dependencies, but this also requires including some special class to load classes from JARs inside the distributed JAR.

Anyway, you can always customize the packaging phase, and you can extract the archive to see what it actually contains.